# Does the prefix '단' generally mean something like 'awaited' or 'desired'?

Tags: vocabulary, etymology

I was asking a Korean friend called 단비 what her name meant in Hanja, and she surprised me by explaining that it was a pure Korean name, meaning a rain (비) that has been long-awaited ([from naver](http://dic.naver.com/search.nhn?dicQuery=%EB%8B%A8%EB%B9%84&query=%EB%8B%A8%EB%B9%84&target=dic&ie=utf8&query_utf=&isOnlyViewEE=&x=0&y=0): *꼭 필요한 때 알맞게 내리는 비* ).

Is there any more general pattern with `단` + noun?

Answer (score 2):

> 단 = 달다 = taste of sugar

1) 단비 : 가뭄에 내리는 비는 적절하다. 참 달게 느껴진다.

During drought, rain is suitable. The rain is felt to us like a
sugar.

2) 단꿈 : 난 백만 장자에 대한 단꿈을 꾼다.

I imagine millionaire but it is just a dream.

3) 단잠=good sleep, 단감=a sweet persimmon, etc.

> @ another uses among several meanings of 단 :

1) 단세포 = one cell

2) 단공장 = factory where we make steel hard.

Answer (score 2):

## Everyone **loves** *sweets*.

It is technically not a prefix. `단` (← `달다` + `-ㄴ`) is the 관형어 (modifier) form of `달다`, meaning `sweet`: having the pleasant taste characteristic of sugar or honey; **pleasing in general**. These words below are *compound words* (합성어) made with the `단`. Note, you should not *space* them when you write these.

- `단잠` (`단`<sub>sweet</sub> + `잠`<sub>sleep</sub>): a pleasing sleep; a refreshing, deep sleep. The slang for this: `꿀잠` (`꿀`<sub>honey</sub> + `잠`<sub>sleep</sub>).
- `단꿈` (`단`<sub>sweet</sub> + `꿈`<sub>dream</sub>): a sweet dream; a pleasing dream.
- `단맛` (`단`<sub>sweet</sub> + `맛`<sub>taste</sub>): a taste of sweetness; sweetness.
- `단비` (`단`<sub>sweet</sub> + `비`<sub>rain</sub>): timely, opportune rain.
- `단것` (`단`<sub>sweet</sub> + `것`<sub>thing</sub>): sweets.
- `단물` (`단`<sub>sweet</sub> + `물`<sub>water</sub>): sweet water; *soft water*; *fresh water*; a part containing the essence.
- `단내` (`단`<sub>sweet</sub> + `내`<sub>smell</sub>): sweet smell.
- `단김` (`단`<sub>sweet</sub> + `김`<sub>steam (gas)</sub>): a main flavor or carbon dioxide that makes a food or drink taste good; especially, carbon dioxide in soda or beer.
- `단침` (`단`<sub>sweet</sub> + `침`<sub>saliva</sub>): the saliva dropped when one is drooling over food.
- `단감` (`단`<sub>sweet</sub> + `감`<sub>persimmon</sub>): *Diospyros kaki*; or, a sweet name for a persimmon.
- `단씨` (`단`<sub>sweet</sub> + `씨`<sub>seed</sub>): a sweet corn. (But I have never heard this word ever.)
- `단술` (`단`<sub>sweet</sub> + `술`<sub>alcoholic drink</sub>): [the sweet alcoholic drink.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dansul)
- `단밤` (`단`<sub>sweet</sub> + `밤`<sub>chestnut</sub>): a sweet, yummy chestnut.
- `단배` (`단`<sub>sweet</sub> + `배`<sub>stomach</sub>): one's stomach appetitive for food.
- `단국` (`단`<sub>sweet</sub> + `국`<sub>soup</sub>): a soup (especially, not glutinous one.) with a sweet flavor. (You should know what Korean soups look like to use this word.)

---

### Do not get confused with

1. The other `단` (← `달다` + `-ㄴ`); it is also the 관형어 (modifier) form of `달다`, but here `달다` is a different word, meaning `to be red-hot`.

   - `단솥` (`단`<sub>heated</sub> + `솥`<sub>pot</sub>): a heated pot.
2. Sino-prefixes that sound `단-`: `單` (solo), `短` (short), and et cetera.

   - `단술` (`단(單)-`<sub>one</sub> + `술`<sub>spoon</sub>)
   - `단신` (`단(單)-`<sub>sole</sub> + `신(身)`<sub>body</sub>)
   - `단신` (`단(短)-`<sub>short</sub> + `신(身)`<sub>body</sub>)
   - `단벌` (`단(單)-`<sub>sole</sub> + `벌`<sub>clothes</sub>)
   - `단세포` (`단(單)-`<sub>uni-</sub> + `세포`<sub>cell</sub>)
   - `단숨에` (`단(單)-`<sub>one</sub> + `숨`<sub>breath</sub> + `-에`<sub>with</sub>)
   - `단박` (`단(單)-`<sub>one</sub> + `박(likely 拍)`<sub>beat</sub>)
   - `단번` (`단(單)-`<sub>one</sub> + `번(番)`<sub>the number of times</sub>)